# PHP page refreshes. Ajax not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Why does `22.php` not show the result in the div?

1) I do not get error message after I click submit.
  2) I can see the tab of the page reloads quickly and the entered text fields are cleared.
  3) No error message or result shows.

```
<html>    
    <head>
      <title>My first PHP page</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" 
         src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {            
        $("#btn").click(function(event){
           event.preventDefault();
           var myname = $("#name").val();
           var myage = $("#age").val();
           yourData ='myname='+myname+'&myage='+myage;
                $.ajax({
                  type:'POST',
                  data:yourData,//Without serialized                  
                  url: '23.php',
                  success:function(data) {
                     if(data){
                        $('#testform')[0].reset();//reset the form
            $('#result').val(data);
                        alert('Submitted');
                     }else{
                        return false;
                      }                        
                   };
                 });                    
            });             
         });
    </script>
   </head>
    <body>
      <form method="post" id="testform">
        Name:
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />Age:
        <input type="text" name="age" id="age" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn" />
      </form>
      <div id='result'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
    if ( isset($_POST['name']) ) { // was the form submitted?
        echo "Welcome ". $_POST["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "You are ". $_POST["age"] . "years old<br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: HTML form resides in 22.php and the result is intended to be taken from 23.php in which echo Welcome message with age. That welcome message should be displayed in 22.php.

Comment: Since yesterday, I have been spending hours with solutions to make this functionality. Everything seem correct. But still not working.

Comment: Okay, I've reverted the change for you. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: sir, have you checked the working functionality? Have you corrected any mistakes in my code and published anywhere here because I cannot see any code from your comment. I am new to stackoverflow and still familiarizing with there as well. :) .Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: I'm referring to some edits I made to your question itself, I haven't submitted an answer, and due to my lack of experience with PHP, I don't plan to.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery code isn't preventing the browser from submitting the form, thus reloading the page before the Ajax request completes. You should use the `submit` event instead of the `click` one, and including `return false;` at the end to prevent it to actually submit the form and reload the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {            
        $("#testform").submit(function(event){ // Using form's submit event instead of button's click event
           var myname = $("#name").val();
           var myage = $("#age").val();
           yourData ='myname='+myname+'&myage='+myage;
                $.ajax({
                  type:'POST',
                  data:yourData,//Without serialized                  
                  url: '23.php',
                  success:function(data) {
                     if(data){
                        $('#testform')[0].reset();//reset the form
            $('#result').val(data);
                        alert('Submitted');
                     }else{
                        return false;
                      }                        
                   };
                 });   
            return false;                    
            });          
         });
```

Comment: Still not working although I have made necessary changes you showed. Thanks for the reply. Does this work well in your computer?